# Automatic Dependency Management with stack such as `stack add <module>`

Tags: haskell, npm-install, cabal, haskell-stack, yarnpkg

it there a command to tell `stack` to add a dependency in the cabal file? I think of a convenient way like with `npm` or `yarn` (`npm install <module> --save`, `yarn add <module>`). I think it is a bit tedious to manually add a new module in die cabal file. Maybe this functionality could automatically include version information as well.

I know that a cabal file has different targets, so it is not as easy as with `npm` or `yarn`. But I think it would be useful.

Thanks :)

Comment: `stack solver`: Add missing extra-deps to stack project config

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such command in `stack`. But there's an open issue for that:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1933

Comment: Ah, thanks. I couldn't find such an issue in the tracker, must have been blind.